# How to bind Spring cloud config values to @ConfigurationProperties object?

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to populate a `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated class with properties from a yaml file on my cloud config server (Jhipster registry, specifically).

The application is connecting to the server and reading the correct file, as when either the server or the file is unavailable, I get an exception either for the missing host or an unexpected empty file.

However, I cannot access any of the properties in the file.

I am primarily trying to populate a `@ConfigurationProperties` object, but all of the fields are null.

Additionally, trying to use @Value for any of the properties in the file throws an error as the property placeholders aren't found.

I've set the `spring.cloud.config.name` and `profile` values to match the format expected [according to the JHipster docs](https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster-registry/#spring-cloud-config).

Comment: try .properties files instead of .yml. And please show your stack trace

Comment: Replacing with .properties did nothing and there is no stacktrace, there is no error until I get an NPE accessing the uninitialized configuration object.

Comment: Are you able to see these properties using the HTTP API from a browser or using curl? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_quick_start

Comment: Yes, I see them when I hit the endpoint using Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an erroneous configuration, the problem was resolved by removing all special characters from the application name specified in the cloud config bootstrap.yml.