# Consuming Properties at Spring Config Client

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Is there way or reference materials on accessing properties exposed in Spring Cloud Config server at client? I know using @Value, I can get value for one element. 
Is it possible to extend or write a framework which can act as layer to consume all such properties and works as bridge to connecting applications.

Comment: No idea what bridger is, but https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Your link is helpful.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683050/how-to-bind-spring-cloud-config-values-to-configurationproperties-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below Annotations and Configurations

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "your.properties.")
@RestController
public class YourController{

private <dataType> <variableName>
     /* Dont forget to generate setters and getters as this is bean */

}
```

Found solution @spencergibb link and other SO links